# Choose Payment Method

Tags: authorize.net

We would like to implement the payment method using Autherize.net, Kindly let me know suitable payment method.

1] Payment is paid to the admin account by A user
2] After some days payment will transfer to the another user B's account  or refund to the A's account

Kindly let me know the suitable payment method for the implementation,for these 2 steps.

Answer (score 0):

With Authorize.Net, you can accept payment for step 1.  However For step 2, Authorized.Net does not support transferring funds your merchant account to a separate account.